# Bad request on Stack Exchange API with GET questions/{qId}/answers/{aId}/comments

Tags: support, comments, api, stack-overflow-enterprise

I made a few successful requests to the Stack Exchange API for Stack Overflow Enterprise.

I get success with data on getting questions/{qId}/answers with its content, but I cannot get comments for this specific answer. I am getting Bad Request "No method found with this name". I get the URL from API documentation and also double check it with [Swagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swagger_(software)) API—it creates the same path.

What I am doing wrong?
As I have positive responses on previous requests, it cannot be an authentication issue.
I also excluded the path problem/ids problem.

Comment: Did you try opening a ticket at https://s.tk/support or were you redirected here by SE support staff?

Comment: I didn't, but I will raise a ticket then.